# What JS function returns

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have found different behavior of code when function is called / returned in different ways. It is quite confusing. So to clear my doubts I have stripped down the whole code to minumum:

Let us consider a simple function:

```
function f()
{
   //some code
}

var objf = f();
```

**Q1. Now `objf` is undefined. Why? What does `f()` returns?**

```
function f()
{
   //some code
   return this;
}

var objf = f();
```

**Q2. What does `f()` returns?  global object?**

Comment: You're asking how `this` works in JavaScript?

Comment: In the first case it depends on the "some code" part, doesn't it? If the function doesn't explicitly return anything its return value is undefined.

Comment: No I have read enough of `this`? :P Just want to know exactly what happens here as asked in questions. Just want to bit more clear and to sum up my understanding of `this`. I have been reading about it for too long.

Comment: You've observed that the first returns `undefined` and the second returns the global object. So it would seem clear that the default return value is `undefined` when there is no `return` statement, and the value of `this` in your second version is the global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1.  Functions in javascript always return values. The default value is `undefined`, except for constructors, where the default return value is `this`. Since no return value is specified in your Q1 example, the interpreter returns the default value, `undefined`.

Q2.  `this` is a javascript keyword that gets updated by the interpreter depending on application context. In the case of a function that is not called from an object, as in your Q2 example, `this` will refer to the global object.

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: I was writing my own take on this, since it was very similar to how Python works with `return` values, in that case if none is defined, it gives `None` so this means they have a similar philosophy in that regard :) +1

Comment: In strict mode, `this` is `undefined` as well

Answer (score 2):

When you do...

```
function f()
{
   //some code
}

var objf = f();
```

...you're getting the return value of the "f" function, which in this case is undefined, once there's no "return something" statement.

If  you do...

```
function f()
{
   //some code
}

var objf = new f();
```

...you'll instance a new object based on the "f" function prototype. Your objf variable will receive a new object reference, even if your "f" function is empty.

And doing this...

```
function f()
{
   //some code
   return this;
}

var objf = f();
```

..."this", in your case, will be the global object, that's the window object for browsers. 
The this keywork is a reference to the object to which the function is bound, look at this:

```
someobj = {
  f:function(){
    return this;
  }
}

var objf = someobj.f();

objf === someobj; //==>true!!!
```

Comment: and just to add, if we put `return this;` inside function and call it with `new`, it will still return a new object created based on the "f" function prototype - am right?

Comment: The return value of a constructor is used if it is an object; otherwise, `this` is returned from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `objf` will indeed be undefined. As the function doesn't return anything, it wouldn't be sensible to just invent something and return that.

In the second case, `objf` will be the `Window` object.

Comment: Ohkay I know `objf` will be undefined, but why? I know when I use `new` to invoke function, it returns `this` if am not explicitly returning anything. Is is just because am not returning anything explicitly and neither am using anything like `new`?

Comment: It's not that the function doesn't return anything. A function that doesn't have an explicit return, has an implicit `return undefined;`